# Unity 2D C# gameObject does not activate other gameObjects if statements when colliding with each other. Why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

The way this game works is that the game starts off with a Largest Ball. When the rocket hits the large ball it splits into two medium balls and then into two small balls. When the rocket hits the smallest ball it gets destroyed.

The problem I'm having is that when the rocket collides with the ball. The rocket gets destroyed, but the ball does "not" divide into two Large balls and so forth.

I just noticed this and I'm wondering if my problem will be fixed if I turn this code statement to == "smallest ball" instead of !=.

```
    if (target.tag == "Rocket")
    {
        if (gameObject.tag != "Smallest Ball")
        {
            InstantializeBallsonoff();
        }
        else {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(popsounds[Random.Range(0, popsounds.Length)], transform.position);
            //play random audio in the popsounds array at current position of ball
            gameObject.SetActive(false); //deactivate the gameobject
        }
    }
}//ontriggerenter
```

This is the full code for my ball Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

private float forceX, forceY;
private Rigidbody2D ball;

[SerializeField]
private bool moveLeft, moveRight;

[SerializeField]
private GameObject originalBall;

private GameObject ball1, ball2;
private Ball ball1script, ball2script;

[SerializeField]
private AudioClip[] popsounds; //array

// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    ball = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ballspeed();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    ballmovement();
}

void InstantiatingBalls()
{
    if (this.gameObject.tag != "Smallest Ball")
    {
        ball1 = Instantiate(originalBall); //create copy of originalball into ball1
        ball2 = Instantiate(originalBall);

        ball1.name = originalBall.name;
        ball2.name = originalBall.name;

        ball1script = ball1.GetComponent<Ball>(); //get the ball script 
        ball2script = ball2.GetComponent<Ball>();

    }
}//InstantiatingBalls

void InstantializeBallsonoff() {
    InstantiatingBalls();

    Vector3 temp = transform.position; //start from current ball location
    ball1.transform.position = temp;
    ball1script.setmoveLeft(true);
    ball2.transform.position = temp;
    ball2script.setmoveRight(true);

    ball1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 2.5f); //x,y
    ball2.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 2.5f); //x,y

    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(popsounds[Random.Range(0, popsounds.Length)], transform.position);
    //play random audio in the popsounds array at current position of ball
    gameObject.SetActive(false); //deactivate the gameobject

}//InstantializeBallsonoff

public void setmoveLeft(bool moveLeft) { //canMoveLeft
    this.moveLeft = moveLeft;
    this.moveRight = !moveLeft; //moveRight is now false b/c we set moveLeft to true
}

public void setmoveRight(bool moveRight) {//canMoveRight
    this.moveRight = moveRight;
    this.moveLeft = !moveRight;
}

void ballmovement() {
    if (moveLeft) {
        Vector3 temp = transform.position; //current position of ball
        temp.x -= Time.deltaTime; // represent time per frame
        transform.position = temp;
    }

    if (moveRight) {
        Vector3 temp = transform.position; //current position of ball
        temp.x += Time.deltaTime; // represent time per frame
        transform.position = temp;
    }
}

void ballspeed() {
    forceX = 2.5f;

    switch (this.gameObject.tag) {
        //this refers to gameobject that holds this script

        case "Largest Ball":
            forceY = 11.5f;
            break;
        case "Large Ball":
            forceY = 10.5f;
            break;
        case "Medium Ball":
            forceY = 9f;
            break;
        case "Small Ball":
            forceY = 8f;
            break;
        case "Smallest Ball":
            forceY = 7f;
            break;
    }//switch

}//ballspeed

void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D target) {
    if (target.tag == "Ground") {
        ball.velocity = new Vector2(0, forceY);
    }

    if (target.tag == "Right Wall") {
        setmoveLeft(true);
        /*moveRight = false;
        moveLeft = true;*/
    }

    if (target.tag == "Left Wall")
    {
        setmoveRight(true);
        /*moveRight = true;
        moveLeft = false;*/
    }

    if (target.tag == "Rocket")
    {
        if (gameObject.tag != "Smallest Ball")
        {
            InstantializeBallsonoff();
        }
        else {
            AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(popsounds[Random.Range(0, popsounds.Length)], transform.position);
            //play random audio in the popsounds array at current position of ball
            gameObject.SetActive(false); //deactivate the gameobject
        }
    }
}//ontriggerenter


 }//ball
```

This is partial of my code where the rocket gets destroyed when it collides with the large ball & the top. This is the other part that I am having trouble with.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {
    if (target.tag == "Top") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    string[] ballhit = target.name.Split();
    /*array ballhit
    split = deletes the space between two words and make it so it takes 2 spaces in the array*/

    for (int s = 0; s < ballhit.Length; s++) {
        Debug.Log("The array contains: " +ballhit [s]);

        if (ballhit.Length > 1)
        { //ball names will always be more than 1 length "Largest Ball"
            if (ballhit[1] == "Ball")
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }//destroy object
        }//ballhit name length
    }// name increments

}//triggerCollider
```

This is my full Rocket Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Rocket : MonoBehaviour {

private Rigidbody2D rocket;
private float speed = 5f;


// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    rocket = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    rocket.velocity = new Vector2(0, speed); //x, y rocket movement
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) {
    if (target.tag == "Top") {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    string[] ballhit = target.name.Split();
    /*array ballhit
    split = deletes the space between two words and make it so it takes 2 spaces in the array*/

    for (int s = 0; s < ballhit.Length; s++) {
        Debug.Log("The array contains: " +ballhit [s]);

        if (ballhit.Length > 1)
        { //ball names will always be more than 1 length "Largest Ball"
            if (ballhit[1] == "Ball")
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }//destroy object
        }//ballhit name length
    }// name increments

}//triggerCollider

}//rocket
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is much more complicated than it needs to be an therefore the actual error is difficult to find.

First off, your `moveLeft` and `moveRight` bools are mutually exclusive. You need only one of them. I would event prefer to replace both with a `public int currentDirection` which you set to 1 for right and -1 for left.

 Your new ballMovement method could then simply be:

```
void MoveBall()    // C# methods are upper-case by convention 
{
    transform.position += Vector3.right * currentDirection * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

The way you check with which type of ball you are colliding is not very safe. I would suggest you use an enum to differentiate the ball sizes.

```
public enum BallSizes { Largest, Large, Medium, Small, Smallest };    // The different possible values
public BallSize size = BallSizes.Largest;                             // The balls current size, the biggest size by default
```

This also allows you to store your y-axis force values in a matching array and access them easily without the use of a switch or else-if:

```
private float[] forcesY = new float[]{ 11.5f, 10.5f, 9f, 8f, 7f };

void SetBallSpeed() 
{
    forceX = 2.5f;
    forceY = forcesY[(int)size];
}
```

I think the problem you had with the ball not splitting is is connected to this.
Upon collision, you detected the type of ball you collided with, by examining its tag. But you always Instantiate the new balls using the same prefab, and I never saw you change the tag. So what type of ball are you creating?
If you use the method I described above, you can simply assign a general tag "Ball" and handle the rest with the BallSizes-enum. When creating the new balls you can do the following:

```
[SerializedField]            // The SerializedField property makes it show up in the inspector, even though it is private
private Ball ballPrefab;     // Attention: Type "Ball"

public void IsHit()          // Method to execute upon rocket collision
{
    if(ball.size != BallSizes.Smallest)
    {
        Ball leftBall = Instantiate(ballPrefab).  // Notice that, when you assign you prefab as Type "Ball", you directly get the Ball-Component as the return value.
        leftball.direction = -1;
        leftball.size = (BallSizes)(size + 1);    // Add one to size, to get get the next enum value, which is the next smaller size.

        Ball rightBall = ....                     // Do same stuff for the right ball
    }

    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

I don't know how you plan to visualise the type of ball, but you might want to add a `float[] ballScales`, which you use to shrink the ball's actual size, something like: `leftBall.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * ballScales[(int)size]`.

Finally, another reason your collision does not work might well be, that you handle it in two different places. If you destroy the rocket after it detects collision with the ball, nothing has happend to the ball yet. If the ball is checking for collision afterward it will most likely not find the rocket, because you already destroyed it.
 A clean way to solve this, would be to let the rocket notify the ball of the collision:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target) 
{
    if(target.tag == "Top")
        Destroy(gameObject);
    else if(target.tag == "Ball")
    {
        target.GetComponent<Ball>().IsHit();    // We know this component should exist when the object is tagged "Ball"
        Destroy(gameobject);
    }
}
```

You can then remove that from you ball collision and shorten it to this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D target) 
{
    if(target.tag == "Ground")    
        ball.velocity = new Vector2(0, forceY);

    if(target.tag == "Right Wall" || target.tag == "Left Wall")
        direction *= -1;    // Inverts the direction, + <-> -
}
```

Phew, that was a lot.
I hope this is still relevant and answers more questions than it raises.
Happy coding!